# Transferring files from ftp to local system

Tags: batch, ftp, windows-command-prompt

I want to copy a file from FTP and paste it to my local system. I want to run this through a batch file. I am trying this for a week. But I couldn't find the solution. Anyone help me please....

This is my actual work

---

Want to copy a file named "Friday.bat" from ftp://172.16.3.132 (with username and password)
So I use the below coding:

```
@echo off
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open 172.16.3.132
mmftp
((((pasword entered here)))))
binary
get Friday.bat 
pause
```

Result:

---

```
ftp> @echo off
ftp> @ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
Invalid command.
ftp> open 172.16.3.132
Connected to 172.16.3.132.
220 Welcome to ABL FTP service.
User (172.16.3.132:(none)):
331 Please specify the password.

230 Login successful.
ftp> binary
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp> get Friday.bat
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
550 Failed to open file.
ftp> pause
```

Finally, a file named Friday.bat is copied to my local system with 0 bytes, but it will not open.

Comment: What kind of firewall(s) do you have between the FTP server and client? Generally, how are they configured?

Comment: I would recommend trying WinSCP which has some nice scripting features. http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: I am not using any firewall

Comment: While trying to pull the files using ftp, make sure you are on the correct folder/path on the FTP server side.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can download the file manually with your favorite brand of FTP client.
If it **doesn't** work, the problem seems to be on the server side: the FTP Server cannot access the file, for whatever reason (permissions?).
If it **does**, make sure the process executing your batch file has write permission in the current directory, or better, do change the directory prior to downloading.

Pro's would create a temporary directory and and process the file there (but be sure to lock down this directory and clean up afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

ftp doesn't like line two... is it necessary?

[Error 550](http://www.theegglestongroup.com/writing/ftp_error_codes.php) is thrown if either the file doesn't exist, or you do not have correct permissions to the file. Make sure you have global read rights to the file, or that you use the `user` command to login with a known local user to the remote machine that has access rights to the file. Ensure these conditions are correct.

That should fix your problem.